# задержка при прокрутке страницы в мобильной версии

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

На мобильных устройствах происходит задержка при обработке прокрутки.
Как исправить?

```js
$(function(){
    $('.action-news').tabSlideOut({                     //Класс панели
        tabHandle: '.action-toggle-news',                       //Класс кнопки
        //pathToTabImage: 'imgbutton.jpg',          //Путь к изображению кнопки
        //imageHeight: '100px',                     //Высота кнопки
        //imageWidth: '30px',                           //Ширина кнопки
        tabLocation: 'right',                       //Расположение панели top - выдвигается сверху, right - выдвигается справа, bottom - выдвигается снизу, left - выдвигается слева
        speed: 300,                                 //Скорость анимации
        action: 'click',                            //Метод показа click - выдвигается по клику на кнопку, hover - выдвигается при наведении курсора
        //topPos: '200px',                          //Отступ сверху
        fixedPosition: true                     //Позиционирование блока false - position: absolute, true - position: fixed
    });
});
(function($){
    $.fn.tabSlideOut = function(callerSettings) {
        var settings = $.extend({
                   
        }, callerSettings||{});

        settings.tabHandle = $(settings.tabHandle);
        var obj = this;
        if (settings.fixedPosition === true) {
            settings.positioning = 'fixed';
        } else {
            settings.positioning = 'absolute';
        }
        
     
        
        //set initial tabHandle css
        settings.tabHandle.css({ 
            'display': 'block',
            'width' : settings.imageWidth,
            'height': settings.imageHeight,
            //'textIndent' : '-99999px',
            //'background' : 'url('+settings.pathToTabImage+') no-repeat',
            'outline' : 'none',
            'position' : 'absolute'
        });
        
        obj.css({
            'line-height' : '1',
            'position' : settings.positioning
        });

        
        var properties = {
                    containerWidth: parseInt(obj.outerWidth(), 10) + 'px',
                    containerHeight: parseInt(obj.outerHeight(), 10) + 'px',
                    tabWidth: parseInt(settings.tabHandle.outerWidth(), 10) + 'px',
                    tabHeight: parseInt(settings.tabHandle.outerHeight(), 10) + 'px'
                };

        //set calculated css
        if(settings.tabLocation === 'top' || settings.tabLocation === 'bottom') {
            obj.css({'left' : settings.leftPos});
            settings.tabHandle.css({'right' : 0});
        }
        
        if(settings.tabLocation === 'top') {
            obj.css({'top' : '-' + properties.containerHeight});
            settings.tabHandle.css({'bottom' : '-' + properties.tabHeight});
        }

        if(settings.tabLocation === 'bottom') {
            obj.css({'bottom' : '-' + properties.containerHeight, 'position' : 'fixed'});
            settings.tabHandle.css({'top' : '-' + properties.tabHeight});
            
        }
        
        if(settings.tabLocation === 'left' || settings.tabLocation === 'right') {
            obj.css({
                'height' : properties.containerHeight,
                'top' : settings.topPos
            });
            
            settings.tabHandle.css({'top' : 0});
        }
        
        if(settings.tabLocation === 'left') {
            obj.css({ 'left': '-' + properties.containerWidth});
            settings.tabHandle.css({'right' : '-' + properties.tabWidth});
        }

        if(settings.tabLocation === 'right') {
            obj.css({ 'right': '-' + properties.containerWidth});
            settings.tabHandle.css({'left' : '-' + properties.tabWidth});
            
            $('html').css('overflow-x', 'hidden');
        }

        //functions for animation events
        
        settings.tabHandle.click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        
        var slideIn = function() {
            
            if (settings.tabLocation === 'top') {
                obj.animate({top:'-' + properties.containerHeight}, settings.speed).removeClass('open');
            } else if (settings.tabLocation === 'left') {
                obj.animate({left: '-' + properties.containerWidth}, settings.speed).removeClass('open');
            } else if (settings.tabLocation === 'right') {
                obj.animate({right: '-' + properties.containerWidth}, settings.speed).removeClass('open');
            } else if (settings.tabLocation === 'bottom') {
                obj.animate({bottom: '-' + properties.containerHeight}, settings.speed).removeClass('open');
            }    
            
        };
        
        var slideOut = function() {
            
            if (settings.tabLocation == 'top') {
                obj.animate({top:'-3px'},  settings.speed).addClass('open');
            } else if (settings.tabLocation == 'left') {
                obj.animate({left:'-3px'},  settings.speed).addClass('open');
            } else if (settings.tabLocation == 'right') {
                obj.animate({right:'-3px'},  settings.speed).addClass('open');
            } else if (settings.tabLocation == 'bottom') {
                obj.animate({bottom:'-3px'},  settings.speed).addClass('open');
            }
        };

        var clickScreenToClose = function() {
            obj.click(function(event){
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
            
            $(document).click(function(){
                slideIn();
            });
        };
        
        var clickAction = function(){
            settings.tabHandle.click(function(event){
                if (obj.hasClass('open')) {
                    slideIn();
                } else {
                    slideOut();
                }
            });
            
            clickScreenToClose();
        };
        
        var hoverAction = function(){
            obj.hover(
                function(){
                    slideOut();
                },
                
                function(){
                    slideIn();
                });
                
                settings.tabHandle.click(function(event){
                    if (obj.hasClass('open')) {
                        slideIn();
                    }
                });
                clickScreenToClose();
                
        };
        
        //choose which type of action to bind
        if (settings.action === 'click') {
            clickAction();
        }
        
        if (settings.action === 'hover') {
            hoverAction();
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

```css
@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 768px) { 
.action-toggle {
    top: initial!important;
    width: 115px;
    bottom: 0px!important;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
    background: #803514;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    padding: 7px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 27px;
    left: -233px!important;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    letter-spacing: 0.043em;
}


.action-toggle-news {
    top: initial!important;
    width: 115px;
    bottom: 0px!important;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
    background: #148051;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    padding: 7px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 27px;
    left: -118px!important;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    letter-spacing: 0.043em;
}

}
@media (min-width: 769px) {
.action-toggle {
  top: 158px!important;
  width: 115px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
     background: #803514;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  padding: 7px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 24px;
  left: -75px!important;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  letter-spacing: 0.043em;
}
.action-toggle-news {
     top: 291px!important;
  width: 115px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
     background: #148051;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  padding: 7px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 24px;
  left: -75px!important;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  letter-spacing: 0.043em;
}
}
h3.a_text {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
  line-height: 0.7;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
.action-content {
    position: relative!important;
    height: 100%!important;
    overflow: auto!important;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(25px)!important;
    -ms-transform: translateX(25px)!important;
    transform: translateX(0px)!important;
    padding-bottom: 20px!important;
}
.action-content-link {
        font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ff7200;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: -7px!important;
    margin-left: -65px!important;
    position: fixed;
}
.action-content-head {
      text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 0px 11px!important;
    height: 53px;
}
.action * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.action a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.handle {
        top: 152px!important;
}
.action-toggle:hover {
  background: #b0491b;
}
.action-toggle-news:hover {
    background: #65b138;

}
.action-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.action {
  color: white;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 526px;
    z-index: 3000;
    background-color: #344a59;
    border-left: 3px solid #148051;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(523px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(523px);
    transform: translateX(-3px);
    /*-webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    transition: all 0.6s ease; */
}
.action {
    height: auto!important;
}
.action.open {
    height: auto!important;
       color: white;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 526px;
  width:88%;
  z-index: 3000;
  background-color: #344a59;
  border-left: 3px solid #803514;
z-index: 99999999999;

}
/* новости  */

.action-news * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.action-news a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.action-toggle-news:hover {
    background: #65b138;
}
.action-toggle-news {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.action-news {
  olor: white;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 526px;
    z-index: 3000;
    background-color: #344a59;
    border-left: 3px solid #148051;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(523px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(523px);
    transform: translateX(-3px);
    /*-webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    transition: all 0.6s ease; */
}
.action-news {
    height: auto!important;
}
.action-news.open {
    height: auto!important;
       color: white;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 526px;
  width:88%;
  z-index: 3000;
  background-color: #344a59;
  border-left: 3px solid #72bf44;
z-index: 99999999999;

}
/* конец новости*/

@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 500px){
.bloglatestnews7 {
    margin: 0px!important;
    margin-left: 20px!important;
           min-height: 100%;
       
}
.bloglatestnews40 a {
font-size: 16px!important;
    }
    .bloglatestnews40  {
font-size: 16px!important;
    }
    .bloglatestnews6 {
    font-size: 12px!important;
color: #ffffff!important;   
    }
}
@media (min-width: 500px) { 
    .bloglatestnews40 a {
font-size: 18px!important;
    }
    .bloglatestnews40 {
    font-size: 18px!important;  
    }
    
}
 .layer {
 overflow: scroll; /* Добавляем полосу прокрутки */
    width: 265px; /* Ширина блока */
    height: 374px; /* Высота блока */
    padding: 5px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
    border: solid 1px black; /* Параметры рамки */
}

.bloglatestnews1 {
    overflow: hidden!important;
    padding: 0px!important;
       margin: 0px 0px 10px!important;
}

.bloglatestnews2 {
margin: 0px!important;
padding: 0px!important;
float: left!important;  margin-right: 5%!important; width: 45%!important;margin-bottom: 34px!important;
}
.bloglatestnews3 {
margin: 0px!important;
padding: 0px!important;
height: 100%px!important;
overflow: hidden;
}
.bloglatestnews3 img {
width: 100%!important;
border: 0px solid #D2D2D2!important;
margin: 0px!important;
padding: 0px!important;
float: none!important;
display: block!important;
opacity: 1!important;
max-width: none!important;
height: auto!important;
box-shadow: none!important;
border-radius: 0px!important;
}
.bloglatestnews3 img:hover {
opacity: 1!important;
}
.bloglatestnews40 {
margin: 0px!important;
padding: 0px!important;

line-height: 18px!important;
margin-top: 10px!important;
margin-bottom: 10px!important;
text-align: left!important;
text-shadow: none!important;
}
.bloglatestnews40 a {

line-height: 18px!important;
word-break: break-word;
color:#efef24!important;
font-weight: bold!important;
text-decoration: none!important;
text-align: left!important;
text-shadow: none!important;
-moz-transition: 0.3s;
-o-transition: 0.3s;
-webkit-transition: 0.3s;
transition: 0.3s;
}
.bloglatestnews40 a:hover {
opacity: 0.5;
}

.bloglatestnews5 {
margin: 0px!important;
padding: 0px!important;
font-size: 12px!important;
line-height: 15px!important;
text-align: left!important;
font-weight: normal!important;
text-shadow: none!important;
color: #222!important;
}
.bloglatestnews4 {
margin: 0px!important;
padding: 0px!important;

line-height: 18px!important;
margin-top: 10px!important;
margin-bottom: 10px!important;
text-align: left!important;
text-shadow: none!important;
}
.bloglatestnews4 a {

line-height: 18px!important;
word-break: break-word;
color:#57ff02!important;
font-weight: bold!important;
text-decoration: none!important;
text-align: left!important;
text-shadow: none!important;
-moz-transition: 0.3s;
-o-transition: 0.3s;
-webkit-transition: 0.3s;
transition: 0.3s;
}
.bloglatestnews4 a:hover {
opacity: 0.5;
}

.bloglatestnews6 {
margin: 0px!important;
padding: 0px!important;

line-height: 10px!important;
text-align: left!important;
color: #ffffff!important;
text-shadow: none!important;
font-weight: normal!important;
margin-top: 5px!important;
}
.bloglatestnews7 {
margin: 18px!important;
padding: 0px!important;
overflow: hidden!important;
    min-height: 375px;
        margin-left: 20px!important;
    min-height: 100%;
}
 carousel.owlCarousel({
    // Точки под каруселью
    pagination: true
});
```

```html
<div class="action-news" style="line-height: 1; position: fixed; height: 876px; right: -526px;">
<!--<a class="handle" href="#">Смотреть</a> <!-- Ссылка для пользователей с отключенным JavaScript -->
<div class="action-toggle-news" style="display: block; outline: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: -115px;">Новости</div> 
<div class="action-content-head">
    <h3 class="a_text"><span>НОВОСТИ!</span></h3><br>
    <a class="action-content-link" href="/news/">СМОТРЕТЬ ВСЕ НОВОСТИ</a></div>
    <div class="action-content">
<div class="bloglatestnews1">
<div class="bloglatestnews7">{% for  post in news|dictsort:"categ"|slice:":9" %}{% if post.categ == 1 %}<div class="bloglatestnews2">
<div class="bloglatestnews3">
<a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}{{  post.slug.url  }}"><img src="{{ post.image_thumbnail.url }}"></a></div>

<div class="bloglatestnews4"><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}{{  post.slug.url  }}">{{ post.zagolovok }}</a></div><div class="bloglatestnews6">{{ post.publish.date}}</div></div>

{% endif %}{% endfor %}</div></div>
```

Comment: Такое впечатление, что тут не правильная каждая строчка кода. Просто удалите все и перепишите с нуля предварительно посмотрев как реализуют другие.  Ваш скрипт должен выполняться при каждом смещении скрола браузера. Вы приближаете глобальное потепление